# проблема при установке texlive 2022

Tags: latex

При установки texlive с оф.сайта происходит ошибка установки файлов с расширением win32 (см. скрин).
Как исправить ошибку? ОС Windows10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как я понимаю - это онлайн установщик, который качает пакеты прям в процессе установки. Могу предложить 2 варианта: 1) Попробовать выбрать другой репозиторий, откуда качаются файлы в начале установки; 2) Установить через офлайн - скачать iso-образ TeXLive. Если оба варианта не сработают - значит замешаны сторонние факторы, с которыми Вам придётся разбираться самостоятельно (например, блокировка антивирусом).

Comment: Вам бы кракозябры, идущие в следующей после "Installing [002/729" строке декодировать, может, там прямо по-русски написана причина проблемы.